# Opening PHPspreadsheet with Ajax call

Tags: php, ajax, phpspreadsheet

I'm trying to open a spreadsheet (using PHPspreadsheet) using an ajax call, but it won't open it.

```
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : "export.php",
    data : data,
    async : true,
    success : function(){
        window.open('export.php', '_blank');
    }
});
```

This is what I have so far. Without the success function the excel won't open, but with it the data wont pass to the _blank url. Is there a way to pass the data to the _blank page?

Comment: What's the error in your console?

Comment: There is no error. I know the export page works.